# javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this:

```
function OpenVote(id, stemme)  {
  var postThis = 'infoaboutvote.php?id='+id+'&stemme='+stemme;
}
```

and this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
OpenVote(10, CripO);
</script>
```

Why have i done wrong? as you see i want 10 to be "id" and CripO to be "stemme"

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well it'd work but it won't do anything.

Comment: Are you forgetting to return a value here? As it stands, this function won't do anything but create a local variable and assign a string value to it. It is fine as far as it goes, but were you expecting it to actually *do* something?

Comment: I know, seems like i forgot single quotes to 'cripo', thats only what i was asking for to get solved.. :)

Comment: Poster child for badly formed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"CripO" looks like a string to mea -- which means it should probably be surrounded by quotes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  OpenVote(10, 'CripO');
</script>
```

Else, it might be a variable -- in which case you should ensure it is initialized before executing that portion of code.

Also, in your `OpenVote` function, you are assigning an URL to the `postThis` variable ; but this will not do anything else.

Especially, it will not send any kind of Ajax request : you need more code, if you want to send an Ajax request to that URL, and get a result.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt it be `OpenVote(10, 'CripO')`;  -- I mean with 'Cripo' within quotes?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want the function to do? Using the `var` keyword here indicates that that variable should only exist inside the function. If you're trying to set the `postThis` variable outside the function, omit the `var`.